# Eigenvector in the linear transformation(generalized basis).

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let the linear transformation $T : V \to V$ for a vector space $V$.  And say the $B$ be the basis of the $V$

(Surely this case including the standard basis case, $E$. Here the $E$ is a set of the standard basis of the $V$)

Suppose There is a vector, $v$ satisfying $[T]_B : V \to V s.t. [T]_B \bullet v  = \lambda \bullet v $ for  $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

Needless to say, $\lambda$ is a Eigenvalue for the linear transformation, $T$ (or $[T]_B$). So my question is "Is the $v$ is a eigenvector?"

In my thought considering standard basis when the $B = E$, $v$ is a eigenvector for $T(=[T]_B)$.

But the case $[T]_B$ when the $B \neq E$, $v$ is a coordinate vector of the eigenvector $v$ for basis B, Not Eigenvector.

Am I right? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don’t confuse the coordinates of a vector with the vector itself. $[T]_B:V\to V$ makes no sense. The expression $[T]_B$ represents a matrix, not a function. Even if you mean something like $L: v\mapsto [T]_Bv$, that could only make sense if $V = \mathbb K^n$, but that’s not one of the premises in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. The eigenvector $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector in the $B$ basis if $[T]_B \cdot \vec{v} = \lambda \vec{v}$, but it's almost definitely (but not always) not true that $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector in the standard basis. However, if $S$ is the change-of-basis matrix, i.e. $T_E = S T_B S^{-1}$, then $S \vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $T_E$ with the same eigenvalue:
$$T_E (S \vec{v}) = S T_B S^{-1} (S \vec{v}) = S T_B \vec{v} = \lambda (S \vec{v})$$
One way of thinking about this fact is to remember that the eigenvector itself has stayed the same, but it will have different representations in different bases: $S \vec{v}$ is the corresponding vector in the standard basis for $\vec{v}$ in the basis $B$.